# Q&A asking for better A

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16467/how-to-reverse-a-subarray-of-an-array) and provide an answer, also I asked for solution better than my own. Then my question been edited and my request for better solution than my own been removed. Was that a good edit, or should I revert it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out why you thought this sentence had any purpose. Oh, you wanted a better solution than the answer you'd posted? As a general principle, your question should stand on its own: refering to an answer doesn't make sense. In any case, it's obvious that you'd be looking for the best answer (for some value of best that you neglected to mention, that is). This sentence was just noise, and removing it was correct.

Comment: I was the one making the edit and this was exactly my intention. Asking for a better (or "the best") solution was redundant.

Comment: Agreed.  Also, a good way to think of this: it is reasonable for the question to state the metric by which you want answers to be evaluated (e.g., I want the most efficient algorithm -- that specifies the metric, namely the efficiency, e.g., the running time).  It doesn't make sense to ask for an answer that's better than your existing answer, but it would be perfectly reasonable to ask for an algorithm with the best possible running time, or an algorithm with running time asymptotically better than $O(n^2)$.